# timeout jquery first time works second time not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, session, logout

Hi friends i have the  jquery  logout function scripts the scripts works first time it means  when we click Yes, Keep me signed in button stay the page.   we need after 10 second again works the function  untle the logout is done .  please help me my fiends . any idea about solve this problem the is simple logout function scripts

```js
 
String.prototype.format = function() {
  var s = this,
      i = arguments.length;

  while (i--) {
    s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
  }
  return s;
};

!function($) {
  $.timeoutDialog = function(options) {

    var settings = {
      timeout: 1200,
      countdown: 60,
      title : 'Your session is about to expire!',
      message : 'You will be logged out in {0} seconds.',
      question: 'Do you want to stay signed in?',
      keep_alive_button_text: 'Yes, Keep me signed in',
      sign_out_button_text: 'No, Sign me out',
      keep_alive_url: '/keep-alive',
      logout_url: null,
      logout_redirect_url: '/',
      restart_on_yes: true,
      dialog_width: 350
    }    

    $.extend(settings, options);

    var TimeoutDialog = {
      init: function () {
        this.setupDialogTimer();
      }, 

      setupDialogTimer: function() {
        var self = this;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
           self.setupDialog();
        }, (settings.timeout - settings.countdown) * 1000);
      },

      setupDialog: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.destroyDialog();

        $('<div id="timeout-dialog">' +
            '<p id="timeout-message">' + settings.message.format('<span id="timeout-countdown">' + settings.countdown + '</span>') + '</p>' + 
            '<p id="timeout-question">' + settings.question + '</p>' +
          '</div>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
          modal: true,
          width: settings.dialog_width,
          minHeight: 'auto',
          zIndex: 10000,
          closeOnEscape: false,
          draggable: false,
          resizable: false,
          dialogClass: 'timeout-dialog',
          title: settings.title,
          buttons : {
            'keep-alive-button' : { 
              text: settings.keep_alive_button_text,
              id: "timeout-keep-signin-btn",
              click: function() {
                self.keepAlive();
              }
            },
            'sign-out-button' : {
              text: settings.sign_out_button_text,
              id: "timeout-sign-out-button",
              click: function() {
                self.signOut(true);
              }
            }
          }
        });

        self.startCountdown();
      },

      destroyDialog: function() {
        if ($("#timeout-dialog").length) {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          $('#timeout-dialog').remove();
        }
      },

      startCountdown: function() {
        var self = this,
            counter = settings.countdown;

        this.countdown = window.setInterval(function() {
          counter -= 1;
          $("#timeout-countdown").html(counter);

          if (counter <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(self.countdown);
            self.signOut(false);
          }

        }, 1000);
      },

      keepAlive: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.destroyDialog();
        window.clearInterval(this.countdown);

        $.get(settings.keep_alive_url, function(data) {
          if (data == "OK") {
            if (settings.restart_on_yes) {
              self.setupDialogTimer();
            }
          }
          else {
            self.signOut(false);
          }
        });
      },

      signOut: function(is_forced) {
        var self = this;
        this.destroyDialog();

        if (settings.logout_url != null) {
            $.post(settings.logout_url, function(data){
                self.redirectLogout(is_forced);
            });
        }
        else {
            self.redirectLogout(is_forced);
        }
      }, 

      redirectLogout: function(is_forced){
        var target = settings.logout_redirect_url + '?next=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        if (!is_forced)
          target += '&timeout=t';
        window.location = target;
      }
    };

    TimeoutDialog.init();
  };
}(window.jQuery);
```

```css
/* Some default button styles */
button {font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-align: middle;}
button {line-height: normal; *overflow: visible;}
button {cursor: pointer; -webkit-appearance: button;}

button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.button:hover, button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.button:focus, button:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  outline: none;
}

/* Timeout Dialog Styles */
.timeout-dialog {
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eeeeee url("../imgs/timeout-icon.png") no-repeat 15px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.timeout-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
.timeout-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}
.timeout-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.timeout-dialog  ~ .ui-widget-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.4;
  -moz-opacity: 0.4;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.timeout-dialog p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 80px;
}
#timeout-keep-signin-btn {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #0f5895;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#377bb2), to(#0f5895));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #377bb2, #0f5895);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #377bb2, #0f5895);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #377bb2), color-stop(100%, #0f5895));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #377bb2, #0f5895);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #377bb2, #0f5895);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #377bb2, #0f5895);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#377bb2', endColorstr='#0f5895', GradientType=0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}
#timeout-sign-out-button {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#timeout-countdown {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <h1>  logout function </h1>
  
  
  
  
  
    
<script type="text/javascript">

 $.timeoutDialog({timeout: 10, countdown: 6, logout_redirect_url: 'https://google.com', restart_on_yes: false});

</script>
```

Comment: If you click stay on this page, logout is not happening subsequently?

Comment: Yes. we too  want to display the timer every particular time intervel